# Why is my Camel Netty route adding newlines to the start of my JMS messages?

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I have a Camel Netty route that takes XML sent to a server port and places it in a JMS message. After the first message, every other message has a newline at the top of the message, causing my XML to fail to unmarshall when a GUI receives it.

My route look like this:

```
<route>
        <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:5150?decoders=#customFrameDelimeterDecoder,#string-decoder&amp;encoder=#string-encoder"/>
         <to uri="jms:topic:my.company.topic"/>

</route>
```

Note: The XML is not newline terminated, hence the need for a custom frame delimeter decoder.

Comment: Why don't you add a log to see how it looks before the jms endpoint? And use a jms client to browse the queue and see how it looks.

Comment: I tried that, there is no white line in the log.

Comment: And you browed your jms endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
    <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:5150?textline=true&delimiter=NULL"/>
```

The problem is that `camel-netty4` is [adding a delimiter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/3505e718db48cc0d8be5b47f6c4030c958d93a5f/components/camel-netty4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/netty4/NettyHelper.java#L56) to your message because of the codec text, so it seems that it is putting a empty string at the end of your message.

You could also try to add `autoAppendDelimiter` to false. [According to docs](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html):

> **delimiter**  | LINE | The delimiter to use for the textline codec. Possible values are LINE and NULL
>
> **autoAppendDelimiter** | true | Whether or not to auto append missing end delimiter when sending using the textline codec.

Cheers!

EDIT:
Sorry, I was trying to answer your other question that was marked as duplicated. But maybe this answer also fits. Let me know.