# Why is my Camel Netty route adding empty messages after an EOL delimiter?

Tags: apache-camel, jms, netty, blueprint-osgi

I have a route like the following:

```
<route>
    <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:5150?textLine=true"/>
     <to uri="jms:topic:my.company.topic"/>
</route>
```

The messages being sent to the tcp port are simple text messages terminated by EOL. But if I add a log statement between the 'from' and 'to' tags, it shows that Camel is also sending an empty string message after every EOL terminated message. This is also seen at the JMS endpoint.

Comment: And you have connected a tcp client tool to that address and received a message without a new line?

Comment: Hi! Please see my answer at your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372858/why-is-my-camel-netty-route-adding-newlines-to-the-start-of-my-jms-messages/47419849#47419849